# Is it possible to combine an InputStream with a form/multipart upload in Alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to upload large amounts of data as part of a multipart form using Alamofire. Is this possible? I can only find references to doing inputstreams separately to multipart forms.

Comment: For what it is worth, I am using multiple `InputStream`s for the same file but skipping some bytes to do the "chunking". Unfortunately, it seems there's a bug on Alamofire that doesn't limit the `InputStream` and uploads the entire stream. I created an issue here https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3714

Answer (score 0):

No, Alamofire's `MultipartFormData` doesn't support `InputStream`'s, as each part of the multipart data needs to have it's length known ahead of time. However, if you can find a way to do it, feel free to open a PR!